# How to force Office applications to use the default printer?

Tags: microsoft-office, printer, microsoft-office-2019

All Office 2019 applications refuse to respect the system default printer on Windows 10 1903. How do I force them to?

For reference, this is what I've already tried:

- Set default printer via Control Panel, disable Let Windows manage my
  default printer in Settings. This fixed all non-Office apps but
  Office apps continue defaulting to the wrong printer.
- Close all Office apps, enable Let Windows manage my default printer
  in Settings. Open Office app, print to the desired printer. On
  re-opening any Office app they revert to selecting the wrong printer.
- Set LegacyDefaultPrinterMode to 1 in
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
  NT\CurrentVersion\Windows instead of using the Settings app.
- Repair Office, then sfc /scannow, then reboot, then try all the above
  again.

What else can I try?

Comment: Have you tried removing the incorrect printer, setting the default (and then verifying the default is selected in Word/Excel, then add the incorrect printer and (verifying if the default printer has not changed).

Comment: Tried it. Office apps behave as long as the printer they insist on defaulting to is uninstalled. On re-installing that printer the Office apps (and only the Office apps) revert to misbehaving. Unfortunately the user does need this printer occasionally. I need it to be both installed and not default.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. The good news is that you can report a bug from inside modern Office apps. It's in the upper right hand corner.

Click "Send a Frown":

[image]

Then fill out the form. You want to do this from the misbehaving print dialog and click include a screenshot.